# Capture SMS response on Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I'm trying to create a Journey that uses a SMS response as criteria to go to the next step.

At my Journey, I will send a message to my customer like this:
"Do you have any problem with your last visit?"

If the answer it's "YES", I want to go to one way at my journey, if the answer it's "NO", I want to go to another way.

Currently, I do the messages in the "Actitivies" panel on the own Journey Builder.

Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few steps that you need to complete to achieve this.

1. Create a Data Extension to store the text reponses. Include two fields; 'MobileNumber' and 
   'Response'. MobileNumber should be the Primary Key.
2. Add an SMS Activity to your Journey, create an outbound message and assign a Next Keyword (you will need to create one in MobileConnect that is not used by any other message).
3. In MobileConnect, create a text response message that uses the Next Keyword that you defined in the previous step. Include a response message and AMPscript [UpsertData](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/) function to insert the reply into the Data Extension you created in step 1. Refer to example code below.
4. Add the DE from step 1 to your Contact Model (in Contact Builder). You will need to create a one-to-one relationship to an existing Attribute Set which has the Mobile Number for the Contact. Join the Mobile Number to the MobileNumber field in your DE.
5. In your Journey, create a Decision Split Activity using Contact Data and choose the DE you created in Step 1 to route the Contact down a path based on if the field **contains** 'yes' or 'no'.

I've created a video of a similar scenario which you can [watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAriYMogGT4&t=90s).

### Sample Text Response Message

```js
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if IndexOf(@response,'yes')>0 or IndexOf(@response,'no')>0 then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

if @validResponse == true then

   UpsertData('SMS Responses', 1, 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Response', @response)

]%%
Thank you for responding!
%%[ else ]%%
Your response is invalid. Please reply 'yes' or 'no'.
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Thx Eliot!
Your answer and your video helps me a lot!

You got a new subscriber! =)

Comment: I have one concern. How do I know, when consumer replied to us, and when I can reply back to the consumer? 
Of course I can upsert to Data Extension *SMS Responses*, not only *Response*, but also *response_date*, using Ampscript now() function. But how I can use this *response_date* in the journey? I want the journey to wait, until consumer replied with YES or NO and after that, send another SMS message. 
I asked here my question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416648/wait-by-attribute-in-2-way-sms-communication-journey-values-in-the-field-chang