# SMS AMPscript Text Response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

Following the below thread, we have created AMPscript for a text response that is associated to a Next Keyword in an SMS Outbound message.
[Capture SMS response on Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296800/capture-sms-response-on-journey-builder)
However no responses are being received or generated.
Any thoughts?

```ampscript
%%[
var @response, @validResponse, @generatedSurveyId
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)] 

/* Retrieve values from entry source data extension */
set @PersonMobilePhone = AttributeValue("PersonMobilePhone") 
set @ContactId = AttributeValue("ContactId")
set @Service_User__c = AttributeValue("Service_User__c")

if @response=='yes' or @response=='no' then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

if @validResponse == true then
   /* Generate a unique SurveyId */
   set @generatedSurveyId = Concat('SURVEY_', Format(Now(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'))

   /* Insert data into DE_Survey_Test */
   InsertData('DE_Survey_Test', 'PersonMobilePhone', @PersonMobilePhone, 'ContactId', @ContactId, 'Service_User__c', @Service_User__c,'Support_Session_taken_place__c', @response, 'SurveyId', @generatedSurveyId)
]%%
Thank you for responding!
%%[ else ]%%
Your response is invalid. Please reply 'yes' or 'no'.
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Can you do a test and see if the the `@response` variable correctly captures the message?

Comment: We have tested using the below and no response received:                                                    
%%[
@response = [MSG(0)]
]%%
Response: %%=v(@response)=%%

Comment: `set` is missing in your code. `%%[set @response = [MSG(0)]]%% Response: %%=v(@response)=%%` should work and properly return the response

Comment: Copy/paste error here, apologies.  set was included when we tested.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic debugging output should indicate the issue.

Once you're finished, just toggle `@debug` to `0` to disable the output.

```ampscript
%%[
set @debug = 1
set @response = MSG(0).NOUN(0)

set @PersonMobilePhone = AttributeValue("PersonMobilePhone") 
set @ContactId = AttributeValue("ContactId")
set @Service_User__c = AttributeValue("Service_User__c")

if @response=='yes' or @response=='no' then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

if @validResponse == true then

   set @generatedSurveyId = Concat('SURVEY_', Format(Now(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'))
   InsertData('DE_Survey_Test', 'PersonMobilePhone', @PersonMobilePhone, 'ContactId', @ContactId, 'Service_User__c', @Service_User__c,'Support_Session_taken_place__c', @response, 'SurveyId', @generatedSurveyId)

]%%
Thank you for responding!
%%[ else ]%%
Your response is invalid. Please reply 'yes' or 'no'.
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat(" ("))
  output(concat("rsp: ", @response))
  output(concat(", pm: ", @PersonMobilePhone))
  output(concat(", cid: ", @ContactId))
  output(concat(", su: ", @Service_User__c))
  output(concat(", vr: ", @validResponse))
  output(concat(", sid: ", @generatedSurveyId))
  output(concat(")"))
endif
]%%
```